# google maps 3 Marker moves when tilt or heading changes

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

maps api v3
browser: IE10

In a HYBRID map I am marking trees on a residential lot.  When I change the tilt or heading on the map, the markers do not adjust and are now out of position.  You can see this by creating a map with one marker over a landmark object like a car or corner and then tilt and/or rotate.

I have googled and seen reference to this in 2011 and 2012, but no discussions since then.

Is there some way to calculate how much I need to move a marker for tilt and heading, or is there some other way to handle this?

Thanks,
Rick

Comment: Do you have an example site that shows the problem? It might be that the marker's anchor is not set correctly. In that case, you should also see the marker being positioned incorrectly if you zoom on the 2D map.

Comment: See this: http://www.zingjet.com/maptest.html

to see the marker move, click 45 degrees under Satellite